# Can you dispel the effects of a potion of heroism?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The [potion of heroism](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-heroism) says:

> For 1 hour after drinking it, you gain 10 temporary hit points that last for 1 hour. For the same duration, you are under the effect of the *bless* spell (no concentration required).

**What happens when *dispel magic* is cast on a person under the effects of this potion?**

- Does the entire potion effect get dispelled?
- Does only the *[bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless)* part get dispelled?
- Does only the non-*bless* part get dispelled?
- Or does nothing get dispelled?

Comment: Relevant to this post: [How *exactly* does Dispel Magic work with multiple effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111997/how-exactly-does-dispel-magic-work-with-multiple-effects), [What happens when you target a “magical effect” with Dispel Magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47717/what-happens-when-you-target-a-magical-effect-with-dispel-magic)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Only the *bless* effect

*Dispel magic* specifies that it ends...

> Any spell ... on the target

While the *bless* effect is simply a spell effect, it still qualifies as a spell for this purpose as evident by [this ruling](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/03/24/dispel-magic-potions/) by Jeremy Crawford, lead designer for 5e:

> Dispel magic can be used against a spell effect created by a potion

*Some tangential evidence*: [this answer to another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/112011/41726) also addresses that *dispel magic* can work against spell effects without having to dispel an entire actual spell.

> Dispel magic ends a spell on one target. It doesn’t end the same spell on other targets.

So you would dispel any magical effect that is a spell effect, but not the additional effect such as the temporary hit points of the *potion of heroism*.